# Display in a custom tab only for "Featured" products in Woocommerce single products

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am trying to set a custom tab to be displayed on product page only for my "Featured" products.
So far I have managed to successfully add a custom tab to global products, but I've failed at adding it solely for the Featured ones. My code so far:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_featured()) {
        $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
            'title'     => __( 'Custom Tab"', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority'  => 100,
            'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
        );
    }

    return $tabs;
}

function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
    echo '<p>Content for new custom tab.</p>';
}
```

How can I display featured products in this custom product tab in single product pages

Comment: Your question code just works fine to display a custom product tab when the current product is featured (so only for featured products)… So what is the problem? … `if ($product->is_featured()) {` is working perfectly to target featured products only.

Comment: Oh, my. It wasn't working when I tried to make it work, I kept getting a blank page, but now I can see that I must have forgotten a closing bracket or something like that. The code works fine, indeed. Thank you, Loic! I really appreciate your help.